# How to prevent windows 11 from deleting js files after System Restore Point usage?

Tags: windows-11

Windows 11 (Home Single Language 21H2 OS build 22000.1281) deletes js files from the project's folders every time
System Restore Point used.
It's so frustrating to find out that you have left with an index.html
and CSS files only.
Is there any way to stop that?

Comment: Not preventive but maybe you can [restore them](https://www.plausiblenonsense.com/2014/02/how-to-restore-files-from-restore-point.html?m=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from the Microsoft community:
Vista list of monitored extensions is hardcoded and there is no way to change it.